# Output more than one line in assembler language

Tags: assembly

My lecturer requires us to write an assembly language code that displays a poem or paragraph. How do I do this? From my knowledge I can only display a single sentence like "hello world".

An example code was this:

```
.model small
        .stack 100h

CR          equ     13d
LF          equ     10d

            .data
message     db      'Hello World', CR, LF, '$'                 ; note the terminating $ 

            .code
start:      
            mov ax, @data
            mov ds, ax

            mov dx, offset message
            mov     ah, 9           ; subprogram for string output
            int     21h                ; call ms-dos to display string

            mov ax, 4c00h
            int     21h

            end start
```

Answer (score 1):

The "$" is the string ending while CR is Carriage return and LF is Line Feed.
Write the entire poem in "message" and put that $ at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply  but i need to write the poem line by line how do i go about that

Comment: @Owitigracie: call that system-call more than once, obviously.

Comment: @PeterCordes  i have done that repeatedly it works only on ht e first two lines but after that there is an error  it doesn't execute

Comment: @Owitigracie: Then your code has a bug, so you should use a debugger and single-step until you find where the values in registers stop matching what you think they should be.